# Prove the congruence

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $p$ is a prime, then

$x^{p-1} \equiv_x (x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-(p-1))$ (mod $p$)

I already tried using the Fermat's Theorem. But I did't solve.

I know the following equation:

$x^p-x \equiv_x (x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-(p-1))$ (mod $p$)

Comment: I don't know what the notation "$\equiv_x$" is supposed to be,
but I suspect a typo: $x^{p-1}$ should be $x^{p-1}-1$.  As it stands
the equation isn't true for any $p$ (try $p=2$ and $p=3$ where you
can easily do it by hand).

Comment: There must be some error in what you wrote down, otherwise it should be $x^p-x \equiv x^{p-1}$ mod $p$...maybe the symbol $\equiv_x$ means something I don't know...